# How to get a value from previous and next row for each row in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with the following fields (and many others but not relevent):

- `ID`
- `Timestamp`

For example:

| ID | Timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-26 14:57:24.292 UTC |
| 4 | 2019-09-23 19:07:45.002 UTC |
| 1 | 2020-05-12 04:34:27.475 UTC |
| 5 | 2021-03-19 14:57:24.292 UTC |
| 4 | 2020-12-21 16:53:24.292 UTC |
| 1 | 2019-02-24 13:27:56.924 UTC |

I want to get the `Start_Date` and the `End_Date` of each row and grouped by `ID` when the `Start_Date` is the Date of the `Timestamp` and the `End_Date` is the Date of the `Timestamp` of the following row when it is grouped by `ID` and ordered by `Timestamp`.

For example:

| ID | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-04-26 | NULL |
| 4 | 2019-09-23 | 2020-12-21 |
| 1 | 2020-05-12 | 2021-04-26 |
| 5 | 2021-03-19 | NULL |
| 4 | 2020-12-21 | NULL |
| 1 | 2019-02-24 | 2020-05-12 |

Or in an ordered way:

| ID | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-02-24 | 2020-05-12 |
| 1 | 2020-05-12 | 2021-04-26 |
| 1 | 2021-04-26 | NULL |
| 4 | 2019-09-23 | 2020-12-21 |
| 4 | 2020-12-21 | NULL |
| 5 | 2021-03-19 | NULL |

How can I do this in StandardSQL ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*,
       date(timestamp) as start_date,
       date(lead(timestamp) over (partition by id order by timestamp)) as end_date
from t;
```